# Integrate real valued function from complex integral

Tags: analysis

I'm having difficulties as to evaluating the complex integral. Also, how should I use its result to evaluate the real valued integral ?

Integrate the function
 $$f(z) = \frac{z}{1 - a e^{-i z}} ;\: a > 1$$
around a suitable rectangle to show
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{a x \sin x}{1 - 2 a x \cos x + a^{2}} dx = \pi \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{a} \right).$$

Comment: First, you should determine the singularities of $f$, and its residues there.

Comment: Thanks julien, evaluating the residue of the singularity  z0=iln(1/a) and using Cauchy's integral theorem solves the complex integral however I do not know how to use this info to solve the real valued integral